# How to give alert on multiple textarea if already texarea id using jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

This is textarea which display multiple text box with taking input using jsp.
I want to give alert to each area if phase is not selected then descripton will not be blank and  descripion should not be exceed after 50 char.

```
<textarea id=<%out.print("desc__" + time);%>  name=<%out.print("desc_" + time);%> rows="4" cols="50" style="margin-left: 85px"></textarea>
```

This is my Javascript Code.

```
function Validation()
    {

        for(var i = 9; i < 23; i++)

        {


            var selectvalue = document.getElementById("phase__"+i).value;
            var desc = document.getElementById("desc__"+i).value;

            if(selectValue == 'Select' && desc!='')
            {
                alert("Please select phase");
            } 
            else if(selectValue!='Select' && desc>10)
            {
                alert("Please select desc with max length 100 n min 10");
            }



            alert(a);                           


        }
        // form will not get submitted..
        return true;
    }
```